# Access NFS share without mapping to drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, nfs

OK, I have found more than enough tutorials online about mapping an NFS share to a drive on WIndows 7 and Windows 2008.  What I need is to know how to access a share without mapping it to a drive.  This is a big issue for me when the Local System account needs to leverage a share drive.  The share I am working with is open to all users so there is no need to map to a user account, but I am trying to determine if there is a UNC that I can use to access the share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use the UNC path of the NFS server and share path - the exact same way that you do for getting to SMB shares without using a mapped drive.

> `\\servername\share\path\`

or

> `\\IP.IP.IP.IP\share\path`

Comment: This site isn't a threaded forum, it's a dedicated Q&A site. @DarrenMB - post your question as a new question, following all the "how to ask a good question" guidance, including whether this question is more appropriate for here or for SuperUser